# ASP.NET app integration with GSA with Kerberos

Tags: asp.net, kerberos, google-search-appliance

Our company purchased GSA (GSA 6.8.0.G.30), and we are trying to 
integrate search into our portal (an ASP.NET) application. The 
Kerberos is already configured on GSA, I can use IE to do a secure 
search by using the default_frontend, and I can get back secure result 
without go thru the login form.

However, we have some challenge when we are trying the integration 
search to our Portal, from our ASP.NET code, we can obtain user's 
**WindowsIdentity** and create a **WindowsImpersonationContext**, we then use 
a HttpWebRequest object to submit a search, GSA first response with 
**302**, and a transport URL "https://my_gsa_hostname/security-manager/ 
samlauthn?SAMLRequest=fZLLTsM...", then we create a new request points 
to the new URL, GSA returns 401-unauthorized.

Anyone can shed us a light?

Answer (score 1):

The WindowsIdentity and WindowsImpersonationContext can not delegate by default.  You'll need to set up the delegation of trust.  Your request is between sent to the GSA anonymously.   I wrote a blog entry a while back regarding how to write some .NET code to handshake with the appliance.  You can read that here:

http://www.mcplusa.com/blog/2009/06/remotely-calling-the-google-search-appliance-restful-web-services-when-saml-is-enabled/

The key will be getting your website to authenticate your users via kerberos as NTLM is not delegate-able.  So..kerberos to website to GSA.

Before the Universal Login Manager, we use the Windows Saml Bridge for silent authentication.  There is a great document describing to set up kerberos

http://code.google.com/p/google-saml-bridge-for-windows/wiki/ConfigKerberos